# c# - How to save form data after submitted

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a bunch of select tags whose option value I want to save even after the form is submitted. Currently, the value resets to the top value after submission.

I tried the following method but it doesn't work! It selects the last option of the for loop in this code.

```
<select class="form-control" id="selYear" name="selYear">
   @for (var i = 2016; i > 1999; i--){            
      if(IsPost){
       <option value="@i" selected='@(Request.Form["selYear"].Equals(i.ToString()) ? "selected" : "")'>@i</option>
      } 
      else {
       <option value="@i" >@i</option>
      }
    }
</select>
```

Does anyone have a solution for this? Please provide some sample codes/examples.

Comment: What do you mean save them? You can just return to the Controller and send the Model data to the return ActionView.

Comment: I don't want the value being reset after submission. For eg, in this form, the default value is 2016 when the page loads. But if I select 2014 and submit the form, I want the value to stay 2014. It resets back to 2016 in this case. 
Could you please show me an example of how to use the controller and model to do this? @Aizen

Comment: Why don't you use a `DropDownList`?

Comment: Do not manually generate you html. Use `@Html.DropDownListFor()` to strongly bind to you model property. Suggest you go to the MVC site and work through the tutorials to lean the basics of MVC

Comment: If you're looking to just post data without updating the UI, I would recommend looking into web api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually selecting every line and the browser decides to use the last.  Modify that line to look something like this:

```
<option value="@i" @(Request.Form["selYear"].Equals(i.ToString()) ?  
                        "selected" : "")>@i</option>
```

Comment: He should use a `Html.DropDownListFor()`.

Comment: This actually works! I thought the shorthand if statement should always be on the right side of an "=" sign as it returns a value which should be assigned to something. Nevertheless, this works for me! @RudyTheHunter thanks :)